# Best seat for sleeping on megabus red-eye trip in USA?

Tags: seating, sleeping, megabus

Do all the seats on megabus lean back?

Are some some seats better for sleeping than the others?

I am planning a 9-hour trip, and I would like to be able to sleep.

Comment: Which country and route? There's probably some variation. That said, in my experience of overnight MegaBus in the UK, the biggest limit on sleep was noisy passengers, not the seat...

Comment: Sorry, I'm in US. I don't worry about noise so much, but I want to be in a comfortable position.

Comment: If you can get a seat with no one sitting next to you, that will trump all other considerations.

Comment: I am not sure about MegaBus in particular, but I get motion sick when I must do a long ride behind the rear wheels. The closer I am to the front, the better. Not sure how other things, like lights and noise, are in the front of a mega bus though.